# How to filter and order WP Query on Post loop using two values?

Tags: wordpress, loops, filtering

Ideally I would like to show only future posts/events (today and future's events) but order by start date. Right now, the function to hide past events is working, but the order is by the "end date" and I would like to order by "start date".

```
/*
Events Category Template
*/

// get posts
$posts = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'category_name'     => 'agenda',
    //'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'          => "event_date_end",
    'meta_compare'      => '>=',
    'meta_value'        => date_i18n("Ymd"),
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
 );

$posts=get_posts($posts);

get_header(); ?>


<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="cat-title"><?php echo single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
        <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
            <div id="left-area">
            <?php if( $posts ): ?>

                <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
                    setup_postdata( $post );?>

                               <!-- content goes here -->

                <?php endforeach; ?>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            </div> <!-- #left-area -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- #content-area -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php

get_footer();
```

Start Date Custom Field: event_date_start

End Date Custom Field: event_date_end

Comment: Shouldn't `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` be `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` as you're not comparing numbers but date strings?

Comment: @cabrerahector Thanks! I just changed as you suggested. But right now, the only thing Im telling/referring is the END DATE, which is filtering. I need to order by START DATE (event_date_start)

Comment: In that case, this will probably do: change `'meta_key' => "event_date_end"` to `'meta_key' => "event_date_start"`.